# Using Litetext in my project

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I have a Java project in Eclipse which requires the use of captcha. I found a library online named **litetext** here: https://code.google.com/p/litetext/

Now, I have absolutely no idea how to use this library. I checked out the **litetext** project to my Eclipse workspace but how do I use this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the build directory, you find a file named "litetext.jar".

Just add this as a dependency of the project where you want to use this library.

This can be done with Right-Click on the Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add.
You can also open the Properties view by selecting Project -> Properties within the top menu bar.